# Creating arrays in QML, not objects

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, qml, qt5

I want to create an array inside QML. [Pyotherside guide](https://pyotherside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#data-type-mapping) says that JS Array converts to python list. But when I create any array it appears to be object, not array.
I tried to create arrays in different ways like

```
var mydata = [1, 2];
```

but mydata.isArray returns False, typeof mydata returns "object"
Is there any way to create JS Array?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to check whether variable is array is to use Array.isArray(mydata). typeof mydata will always return "object". So in other words mydata is JS Array.